# flink: use allowedLateness in flink sql api

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I'm using flink sql api and I have a sql like

```java
Table result2 = tableEnv.sqlQuery(
    "SELECT user, SUM(amount) " +
    "FROM Orders " +
    "GROUP BY TUMBLE(proctime, INTERVAL '1' DAY), user"
);
```

Can I enable ["allowedLatenness"](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#allowed-lateness/) and [getting late data as a side output](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#getting-late-data-as-a-side-output)

Answer (score 1):

Late data handling is not supported in Flink SQL yet (version 1.5.0). Late rows are just dropped.

Comment: Is there any plan to support it?

Comment: Yes, we would filter late rows during the table scan and redirect them to a side output. However, I'm not aware of any concrete steps that have been done in that direction.